# How to repair this kitchen drain pipe?

Tags: kitchens, pipe, kitchen-sink

I bought an house.

I've this kitchen "ripped" drain pipe. It is a cast iron pipe.

How can I fix it to allow to connect my kitchen sink pipes ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Cast does not bend or rip, it cracks and is heavy/thick.  That pipe is thin and might be copper or thin steel type.  It need to be replaced and looks like you need to get behind that wall, either by removing it or from the other side.

Comment: You'd do us a service by either adding your location to your profile or mentioning it in your question. Plumbing practices vary by region.